# Windows Phone 8 development

Tags: windows-phone-8

Could you confirm whether Windows Phone 8 ISO or SDK is available to install with VS2012 Ultimate which I have installed on Windows 7 Home Basic.

Since unable to install Phone 8 environment as get message about Windows 8 needed, but have Windows 8 Preview running in VMWARE workstation.

Please suggest some workaround so that can dev with Windows Phone 8 with existing setup.

Thanks.
Maneesh

Answer (score 0):

The Windows Phone 8 SDK requires Windows 8 as specified [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35471). The Windows Phone 7.8 SDK supports Windows 7, but won't let you develop Windows Phone 8 apps just 7.5 and 7.8 apps.

The Windows Phone 8 SDK uses Hyper-V to run the emulator which is why you need Windows 8. [This article](http://www.veeam.com/blog/nesting-hyper-v-with-vmware-workstation-8-and-esxi-5.html) claims to define how to use Hyper-V inside a VMware Workstation 8 VM. Following those steps it should be possible to install VS2012 and the Windows Phone 8 SDK inside the VM and get everything running.